# how to access EL inside style tag?

Tags: css, jsp, el

```
<style>
        .tableborder {
                    border-color: ${myClassobj.color}; }
 </style>
```

I want to access dynamic color inside style tag.Like table border I also wanted to apply dynamic color to text inside table or page background color.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Use the `class` or `style` attributes of the HTML you are generating.

Comment: Client requirement is such that he/she will choose color of form elements of own choice.For ex: Client A wants color border of table or font of text should be green then our page containing table/text should be in green.

Comment: @Jasper de Vries -Page is having multiple text elements and each element is using  same class ,so my problem is instead of using jstl(${myobj.color}) at multiple locations simply assign dynamic color to class say myclass and assign this class to those text elements.

Comment: So, don't use `class` but `style`...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style type="text/css">
            .tableborder {
                        border-color:<c:out value="${myClassobj.customerColor}"/>;
                         }
</style>
```

This way we can set colour at run time.